# SSL and TLS 1.0 PCI Compliance

Tags: .net, ssl, tls1.2, pci-compliance

We recently received a couple of notifications from major gateways stating that 
"The PCI Council says you must remove completely support for SSL 3.0 and TLS 1.0. In short: servers and clients should disable SSL and then preferably transition everything to TLS 1.2."

My question is, if we disable 3.0 and TLS 1.0 completely on our servers and make the required adjustments on our code, will our customers, who use old browsers, still be able to access our website? unfortunately we know that at least 10% of our customers uso IE 8.

I am confused about this change and want to make sure I understand whether or not there is an impact on the customers' side (website's visitors)

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

> unfortunately we know that at least 10% of our customers use IE 8.

IE 8 at least on Windows XP does not support TLS 1.1 or TLS 1.2. If you are on the obsolete platform XP you would need to use Firefox or Chrome as long as these are still available for this platform.

Comment: Thanks Steffen, based on your answer, this is not only a change on the IT side but also on the customer's side correct. do you know how we can test or replicate the error message that customers (with IE 8) will see if they try to hit our website after TLS 1.2 has been enabled?

Comment: @user714142: Use XP with IE8 against a test site which only can do TLS 1.2.?  You can setup such a site yourself and maybe edit the hosts file of the windows machine so that it associates the test site with a valid hostname contained in a certificate you have.

Comment: See https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000221207#InternetBrowsers it has info + the URL to a tls 1.1+ site only

Answer (score 0):

You should try to make passing PCI compliance scans a priority. On a server running Apache, go to your `httpd.conf` file and you will need this line in the appropriate section:

```
SSLProtocol -All +TLSv1.2
```

Find the official documentation at https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslprotocol.